# ZipForge: how to add Empty folder to archive?

Tags: delphi, zip

Question in the title.
I didn't manage to find a way to add an empty folder to the archive or create an empty directory inside of the archive.

It works fine if I just add files and folders by mask, but I have to add files one by one and not all together (there are reasons).

How can I create an empty directory inside archive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to create empty folder more correctly.
As David Heffernan stated, we should add empty file titled as our folder:

```
FullFolderName = 'foo\bar'
ZipForge.AddFromBuffer(FullFolderName, nil^, 0);
```

**Note:** *bar* is our empty folder which should be in the *foo* folder. Do not put backslash at the end of the path.

And after that we should change the attribute of the "folder" inside the archive, because our "folder" has the same attribute as a file. To do this we should call:

```
ZipForge.ChangeFilesAttr(FullFolderName, ZFDirectoryAttr);
```

ZFDirectoryAttr is a constant declared in ZipForge.pas and equals to 16.

Answer (score 0):

ZIP files do not explicitly support the concept of folders. Instead you specify file names with path separators, and ZIP file tools infer the intended structure that way.

So the way you *fake* an empty folder is to create an empty file with a name that ends in a trailing path separator.

I don't know ZipForge, but in the built in `TZipFile` you'd do it like this:

```
ZipFile := TZipFile.Create;
try
  ZipFile.Open('C:\desktop\temp.zip', zmWrite);
  ZipFile.Add(TBytes(nil), 'foo/');
finally
  ZipFile.Free;
end;
```